# Expo router documentation contex not working

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I started using the expo router and got my setup done.
My main _layout.js

```
import { Slot } from "expo-router";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { Provider } from "../context/auth";
import { Slot } from "expo-router";
import { Provider } from "../context/auth";

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <Slot />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

I followed the expo documentation and created the Provider and auth context from here: https://docs.expo.dev/router/reference/authentication/

I have the exact same context/auth.js from here, but I have a problem.

```
 ERROR  Error: Attempted to navigate before mounting the Root Layout component. Ensure the Root Layout component is rendering a Slot, or other navigator on the first render.
```

This is happening because, I think, that useEffect is called before  is returned and can't use router.replace()

Do you have any solution for this? Or how could I implement this using layouts?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Followed this thread and finally solved it.

https://github.com/expo/router/issues/740

more specific: https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/23722

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.